# Deleting array elements based on key without using unset

Tags: php

I have two arrays and need to iterate through the first and remove elements in the second that have keys that match the values in the first array.

```
$array1 = array(23456,98765);
$array2 = array(12345 => "Andrew", 23456 => "Bobby", 98765 => "Charles");

foreach ($array1 as $key) {
  unset($array2[$key]); 
}
```

However, I can't use "unset" because "unset cannot be used in a completely type safe way". What is another way I can do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "unset cannot be used in a completely type safe way"? This question is the only Google result for that exact quote.

Comment: It's an alert I get at work when I try this. Solution is below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a map, so use removeKey();

```
foreach ($array1 as $key) {
  $array2->removeKey($key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you want to delete a array element without `unset()`? You could only create a new array like this:

```
$array1 = array(23456,98765);
$array2 = array(12345 => "Andrew", 23456 => "Bobby", 98765 => "Charles");

$result = array_flip(array_diff(array_flip($array2), $array1));
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [12345] => Andrew )
```

Comment: You'll also be deduplicating the array in this process... maybe not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty trivial, you're looking for an array diff:

```
$array2 = array_diff_key($array2, array_flip($array1));
```

See http://php.net/array_diff_key